# Is this SQL query even possible in Drupal 7?

Tags: database

I'm trying to find a way to run this query in a custom drush command to dump chunks of data from the DB into CVS files.

The query works fine directly in the terminal but I was wondering how would you do it in code for Drupal 7? I guess I can transform a PHP array to a CVS file but wanted to know if Drupal has a way to write more complex queries like this :)

Big thanks in advance!

Query:

```
SELECT uid, name, mail INTO OUTFILE '/path/sqldumps/result.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
ESCAPED BY '\\'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
FROM users 
WHERE uid != 0
```

Comment: `db_query()` will execute any arbitrary SQL string - are you having a problem using it or have you maybe not tried it yet?

Comment: As a side note the **Views Data Export** module can generate CSV data from the UI.

Answer (score 0):

Drupal has it's own abstraction layer to work with database , this method helps Drupal to work with different kind of databases like PgSQL or even oracle (just a database driver will handle everything).

You can get familiar with this api in : [Drupal Database API](https://www.drupal.org/developing/api/database)

A more exclusive reference could be : [Drupal Dynamic Queries](https://www.drupal.org/dynamic-queries)